# C - Get two closest int numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array which I asked the user to enter. (I asked the number of numbers in the array and I asked for those numbers). 
My question is how do I compare all the numbers and find the two closest ones ?

So, for example if the user enters 4 numbers like: 3, 5, 8, 9. The program should see 8 and 9 as the closest ones ? 
After that I just need to subtract the two closest numbers.

This is my code so far:

```
    int main()
{
    int N;
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (c = 0; c < N; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
```

Comment: Looks like homework?!

Comment: You got the loading part sorted out, but what's your approach for the rest?

Comment: One way to find the "closest" numbers is to subtract numbers, and the two with the smallest difference is the pair you want. Incidentally that also solves your second problem.

Comment: @dwo So? Homework questions are (unfortunately) allowed, given that they follow the rules: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array first.
Take 3 temp variables n1=0, n2=0, diff=0.
Iterate the sorted array assign n1, n2 to a[i], a[i+1], where a[] is the array and i is the iterator.

```
If     absolute(a[i]-a[i+1]) < diff     then 
diff =  absolute(a[i]-a[i+1]);
n1 = a[i]; 
n2 = a[i+1];
```

When the iteration completes you have the closest elements in n1 and n2.
N.B. Please take care of array out of bound for a[i+1], I have just given an approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really want to do your homework, but I kinda liked the task, so here is at least pseudocode.. Rewrite it to C yourself

```
proc findclosest(array)
    int l = int.max, r = int.min, len = array.count
    for i from 0 to len do
        for j from i + 1 to len do
            if abs(array[i] - array[j]) < abs(l - r) then
                l = i
                r = j
            end if
        end for
    end for
end proc
```

Comment: Note `abs(l - r)` certainly overflows on first usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Turbo C program to your question. ..and works perfectly. ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
 int a[30],i,j,n,l=0,m=1;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter no. of elements :");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter array elements:");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
 for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
 {
 for(j=i;j<n-1;j++)
 {
 if(abs(a[j]-a[j+1])<abs(a[l]-a[m]))
 {
   l=j;
   m=j+1;
 }
 }
 }
  printf("Closest numbers are %d and %d",a[l],a[m]);
 getch();
 }
```